# Flutter folder picker

Tags: flutter, dart, filepicker

I have a button on screen, when you click button I need to open some folder picker.
I have searched for package, but I didn't found any package that also support Android and iOS.
Does someone knows some package who will resolve this problem, or something I could use to make solution of picking folder on iOS?

EDIT:

I found way to get directory picker functionality,I didn't test on iOS but in documentation says it works on both (Android and iOS).

```
String path = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
```

With this line above you get new screen to select your directory and get a path like result from that Future.

This is solved using file_picker package.

Answer (score 8):

Use the package file_picker.

Easy to use:

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

if(result != null) {
   File file = File(result.files.single.path);
} else {
   // Do something else...
}
```

Comment: But can you only pick directories, and not showing files?

Comment: If you have done it correctly, you can also select files. Look through the documentation, maybe you find your problem there